# Ubuntu 16.04.01 MATE - Chrome 'Aw snap" crashes

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome, ubuntu-mate

On a fairly fresh install of Ubuntu, Chrome 57.

Chrome is being a real pain. Constantly getting the 'Aw snap' error on multiple tabs, ironically even the actual google support page on that issue (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). Its definitely not tied to a single / specific sites.

I still have stacks of memory available, so its not running out. It can happen either a couple hours after initial load, or almost immediately after I kill all chrome processes and start fresh.

I have tried:

- Removing as many unessential extensions as possible
- Updated to latest version
- Rebooted
- Killed chrome processes and restarted

In `/var/log/syslog` I am getting things like:

```
May  2 15:34:13 nikon kernel: [23673.707007] traps: chrome[678] general protection ip:56439cc9a257 sp:7ffff28aed28 error:0 in chrome[56439b9d0000+6aa4000]
May  2 15:34:29 nikon kernel: [23689.425474] traps: chrome[612] general protection ip:56439c840b57 sp:7ffff28acd50 error:0 in chrome[56439b9d0000+6aa4000]
May  2 15:34:32 nikon kernel: [23692.708588] traps: ScriptStreamerT[855] general protection ip:56439c8493b3 sp:7fc465671180 error:0 in chrome[56439b9d0000+6aa4000]
May  2 15:34:38 nikon kernel: [23698.881207] traps: chrome[876] general protection ip:56439c840b43 sp:7ffff28ae820 error:0 in chrome[56439b9d0000+6aa4000]
May  2 15:35:10 nikon kernel: [23730.732626] traps: chrome[894] general protection ip:56439c848621 sp:7ffff28acfd0 error:0 in chrome[56439b9d0000+6aa4000]
May  2 15:37:09 nikon kernel: [23849.271061] traps: chrome[1034] general protection ip:56439cb40b0a sp:7ffff28ae3d0 error:0 in chrome[56439b9d0000+6aa4000]
May  2 15:38:38 nikon dbus[2936]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service'
May  2 15:39:37 nikon kernel: [23997.351302] traps: chrome[1693] general protection ip:55be77890119 sp:7ffeeadc56d0 error:0 in chrome[55be766f1000+6aa4000]
May  2 15:43:21 nikon org.freedesktop.Notifications[4983]: Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":0".
May  2 15:49:39 nikon kernel: [24599.574516] traps: chrome[2434] general protection ip:55be778a2afd sp:7ffeeadc22e0 error:0 in chrome[55be766f1000+6aa4000]
```

Any ideas how I can even troubleshoot what is wrong / check logs?

Answer (score 1):

Got the same error message after update ubuntu 14.04 -> 16.04.

You can enable logs with command line arguments as stated [here](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging):

> --enable-logging --v=1

For me the resulting file was located here

> ~/.config/google-chrome/chrome_debug.log

Here is an explanation how to find log file for other platforms: http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory

Unfortunately, content of log gives me nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Turns out my RAM was dieing, good time for an upgrade xD